# How to generate json data in below hierarchical format using sql server 2016

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2016

I have a single SQL table which contain Parent and child relationship.I would like to know how to generate json data in below hierarchical format using SQL query (SQL Server 2016). Please check my table structure and needed output json format.

Note: I have already generated below json data using "java script" code but I need to generate this json data via a SQL Server 2016 query..

SQL Server table with record:

```
Id  name    url icon    Parent
----------------------------------
3   LGD NULL    fa fa-dashboard 0
4   GLD NULL    fa fa-dashboard 0
5   FWD NULL    fa fa-dashboard 0
9   Order Outstanding   /ZohoDashboard/9    fa fa-dashboard 3
11  Current Order Status    /ZohoDashboard/11   fa fa-dashboard 4
19  HR Overview /ZohoDashboard/19   fa fa-dashboard 3
20  HR Attrition    /ZohoDashboard/20   fa fa-dashboard 3
21  Shipment Tracking   /ZohoDashboard/21   fa fa-dashboard 3
23  D & D Overview  /ZohoDashboard/23   fa fa-cogs  3
26  HO  NULL    fa fa-dashboard 0
27  Leather Stock Overview  /ZohoDashboard/27   fa fa-cogs  4
28  Leather PO Pending Details  /ZohoDashboard/28   fa fa-cogs  4
29  HR Overview /ZohoDashboard/29   fa fa-cogs  4
30  D & D Production details    /ZohoDashboard/30   fa fa-cogs  4
31  Payment receivable details  /ZohoDashboard/31   fa fa-cogs  26
42  HnS NULL    fa fa-dashboard 0
43  H & S Sales Details /ZohoDashboard/43   fa fa-cogs  42
44  H & S Shoes Factory Order Details   /ZohoDashboard/44   fa fa-cogs  42
45  KHRS    NULL    fa fa-dashboard 0
46  Greenfield Sales Details    /ZohoDashboard/46   fa fa-cogs  45
47  Stock Overview  /ZohoDashboard/47   fa fa-cogs  45
48  Stock Details   /ZohoDashboard/48   fa fa-cogs  42
49  Break Even Overview /ZohoDashboard/49   fa fa-cogs  45
50  Camp Sales Details  /ZohoDashboard/50   fa fa-cogs  45
51  Order Overview  /ZohoDashboard/51   fa fa-cogs  42
52  Order Overview  /ZohoDashboard/52   fa fa-cogs  5
53  Attendance Overview /ZohoDashboard/53   fa fa-cogs  4
54  HR Overview /ZohoDashboard/54   fa fa-cogs  5
55  Order In Value Overview /ZohoDashboard/55   fa fa-cogs  3
56  Leather Stock Details   /ZohoDashboard/56   fa fa-cogs  5
57  tt  /ZohoDashboard  fa fa-cogs  0
58  HR Overview /ZohoDashboard/58   fa fa-cogs  57
15  User Management NULL    fa fa-user  0
16  Menu Master /MenuList   fa fa-user  15
17  User Access /UserList   fa fa-user  15
18  Division Master NULL    fa fa-user  15
25  User List   NULL    fa fa-cogs  15
```

I need Json output format like this:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "name": "LGD",
            "url": null,
            "icon": "fa fa-dashboard",
            "Parent": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "Id": 9,
                    "name": "Order Outstanding",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/9",
                    "icon": "fa fa-dashboard",
                    "Parent": 3
                },
                {
                    "Id": 19,
                    "name": "HR Overview",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/19",
                    "icon": "fa fa-dashboard",
                    "Parent": 3
                },
                {
                    "Id": 20,
                    "name": "HR Attrition",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/20",
                    "icon": "fa fa-dashboard",
                    "Parent": 3
                },
                {
                    "Id": 21,
                    "name": "Shipment Tracking",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/21",
                    "icon": "fa fa-dashboard",
                    "Parent": 3
                },
                {
                    "Id": 23,
                    "name": "D & D Overview",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/23",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 3
                },
                {
                    "Id": 55,
                    "name": "Order In Value Overview",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/55",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 4,
            "name": "GLD",
            "url": null,
            "icon": "fa fa-dashboard",
            "Parent": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "Id": 11,
                    "name": "Current Order Status",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/11",
                    "icon": "fa fa-dashboard",
                    "Parent": 4
                },
                {
                    "Id": 27,
                    "name": "Leather Stock Overview",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/27",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 4
                },
                {
                    "Id": 28,
                    "name": "Leather PO Pending Details",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/28",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 4
                },
                {
                    "Id": 29,
                    "name": "HR Overview",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/29",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 4
                },
                {
                    "Id": 30,
                    "name": "D & D Production details",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/30",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 4
                },
                {
                    "Id": 53,
                    "name": "Attendance Overview",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/53",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 5,
            "name": "FWD",
            "url": null,
            "icon": "fa fa-dashboard",
            "Parent": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "Id": 52,
                    "name": "Order Overview",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/52",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 5
                },
                {
                    "Id": 54,
                    "name": "HR Overview",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/54",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 5
                },
                {
                    "Id": 56,
                    "name": "Leather Stock Details",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/56",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 26,
            "name": "HO",
            "url": null,
            "icon": "fa fa-dashboard",
            "Parent": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "Id": 31,
                    "name": "Payment receivable details",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/31",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 26
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 42,
            "name": "HnS",
            "url": null,
            "icon": "fa fa-dashboard",
            "Parent": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "Id": 43,
                    "name": "H & S Sales Details",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/43",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 42
                },
                {
                    "Id": 44,
                    "name": "H & S Shoes Factory Order Details",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/44",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 42
                },
                {
                    "Id": 48,
                    "name": "Stock Details",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/48",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 42
                },
                {
                    "Id": 51,
                    "name": "Order Overview",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/51",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 42
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 45,
            "name": "KHRS",
            "url": null,
            "icon": "fa fa-dashboard",
            "Parent": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "Id": 46,
                    "name": "Greenfield Sales Details",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/46",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 45
                },
                {
                    "Id": 47,
                    "name": "Stock Overview",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/47",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 45
                },
                {
                    "Id": 49,
                    "name": "Break Even Overview",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/49",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 45
                },
                {
                    "Id": 50,
                    "name": "Camp Sales Details",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/50",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 45
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 57,
            "name": "tt",
            "url": "/ZohoDashboard",
            "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
            "Parent": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "Id": 58,
                    "name": "HR Overview",
                    "url": "/ZohoDashboard/58",
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 57
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 15,
            "name": "User Management",
            "url": null,
            "icon": "fa fa-user",
            "Parent": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "Id": 16,
                    "name": "Menu Master",
                    "url": "/MenuList",
                    "icon": "fa fa-user",
                    "Parent": 15
                },
                {
                    "Id": 17,
                    "name": "User Access",
                    "url": "/UserList",
                    "icon": "fa fa-user",
                    "Parent": 15
                },
                {
                    "Id": 18,
                    "name": "Division Master",
                    "url": null,
                    "icon": "fa fa-user",
                    "Parent": 15
                },
                {
                    "Id": 25,
                    "name": "User List",
                    "url": null,
                    "icon": "fa fa-cogs",
                    "Parent": 15
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my SQL query:

```
select 
    PARENT.MenuId Id, PARENT.MenuName name, NULL url, 
    PARENT.IconCSS icon, PARENT.ParentId parent ,
    (Select 
         MenuId Id, MenuName name, 
         Case 
            When MenuParam = 'Y' And ParentId <> 0 
               Then RTrim(Page) + '/' + RTrim(MenuId) 
               Else RTRIM(Page)  
         End url, iconcss icon, ParentId parent
     from 
         MenuMaster AS Child
     where 
         (CHILD.ParentId > 0) And CHILD.MenuId = PARENT.MenuId  
     FOR JSON AUTO) as Children
from 
    MenuMaster AS PARENT
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT ('items')
```

Current output of json data from this query:

```
{"items":[{"Id":3,"name":"LGD","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":0},{"Id":4,"name":"GLD","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":0},{"Id":5,"name":"FWD","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":0},{"Id":9,"name":"Order Outstanding","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":3,"Children":[{"Id":9,"name":"Order Outstanding","url":"\/ZohoDashboard\/9","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":3}]},{"Id":11,"name":"Current Order Status","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":4,"Children":[{"Id":11,"name":"Current Order Status","url":"\/ZohoDashboard\/11","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":4}]},{"Id":15,"name":"User Management","icon":"fa fa-user","parent":0},{"Id":16,"name":"Menu Master","icon":"fa fa-user","parent":15,"Children":[{"Id":16,"name":"Menu Master","url":"\/MenuList","icon":"fa fa-user","parent":15}]},{"Id":17,"name":"User Access","icon":"fa fa-user","parent":15,"Children":[{"Id":17,"name":"User Access","url":"\/UserList","icon":"fa fa-user","parent":15}]},{"Id":18,"name":"Division Master","icon":"fa fa-user","parent":15,"Children":[{"Id":18,"name":"Division Master","icon":"fa fa-user","parent":15}]},{"Id":19,"name":"HR Overview","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":3,"Children":[{"Id":19,"name":"HR Overview","url":"\/ZohoDashboard\/19","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":3}]},{"Id":20,"name":"HR Attrition","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":3,"Children":[{"Id":20,"name":"HR Attrition","url":"\/ZohoDashboard\/20","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":3}]},{"Id":21,"name":"Shipment Tracking","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":3,"Children":[{"Id":21,"name":"Shipment Tracking","url":"\/ZohoDashboard\/21","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":3}]},{"Id":23,"name":"D & D Overview","icon":"fa fa-cogs","parent":3,"Children":[{"Id":23,"name":"D & D Overview","url":"\/ZohoDashboard\/23","icon":"fa fa-cogs","parent":3}]},{"Id":25,"name":"User List","icon":"fa fa-cogs","parent":15,"Children":[{"Id":25,"name":"User List","icon":"fa fa-cogs","parent":15}]},{"Id":26,"name":"HO","icon":"fa fa-dashboard","parent":0},{"Id":27,"name":"Leather Stock Overview"
```

Comment: how are you querying the database table.  is this from a REST API?  you tend to do the formatting there, what is you server-side framework

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `SELECT FOR` clause, which can format your result in `XML` or `JSON`. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-for-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) link for the documentation.

There is an example on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016) page showing how to use it. An image from the same page is shown below

[image]

Comment: I have tried above query but its not return as per my requirement.please check and advise how to do this...

Comment: @MohammedIsmail can you format your source data as a table to make it clearer? You can use this site : https://senseful.github.io/text-table/

Comment: and what is your current output?